# Which is more efficient: Netty's HashedWheelTimer or Quartz's scheduler?

Tags: netty, quartz-scheduler

[HashedWheelTimers](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.1/api/org/jboss/netty/util/HashedWheelTimer.html) are based on [this 1987 paper](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~nahum/w6998/papers/sosp87-timing-wheels.pdf) about how traditional timers consume O(N) processing to maintain (for N timers), but hashed wheels can consume O(1).  I'm unsure if Quartz's job scheduling just managers timers underneath, or actually uses an O(1) solution under the covers.

Answer (score 2):

The Quartz scheduler is designed for scheduling persistent jobs. So, when Quartz comes up after going down, it can see what jobs were supposed to run but didn't and optionally run th em.

HashedWheelTimer is designed to scale to thousands of timers. They're solving two very different problems.

Comment: I agree they have different feature sets, but that doesn't necessarily mean that I should always use Netty's HashedWheelTimer if I don't need persistence.  Many O(1) solutions have constant overheads that overwhelm O(N) solutions for small N (e.g., Insertion Sort outperforming Quicksort and Heapsort for small N).  If persistence is not an issue, and there is an overhead for using HashedWheelTimers for small N, it would be nice to know where that tradeoff is in this case.